# Using Less with AngularDart components and Bootstrap

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have started to migrate an AngularJS app to AngularDart, using [Vic Savkin's sample app](https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app) as a skeleton.

My existing project uses Less CSS. I am unclear about how to include that in my project.

Specifically, I have Components in the 'lib' folder and CSS in the 'web' folder. I want to be able to define some Less variables at project level, which will be used by Components. I will want to use the Components in other future projects.

Do I need to import the bootstrap.less and variables.less file in each component's less file, or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

At first if you want to use something in `web` and `lib` put it in `lib`. You can import from `lib` to `web` with `package:mypackage/asset/css/mycss.css` but not the other way around.

I guess you will avoid shadowDOM because Bootstrap doesn't work well with it.
If you still want to use shadowDOM you need to add the CSS to each component (might still cause troubles when you have nested components) or modify the CSS selectors.

If you modify the CSS selectors you need to add additional selectors for each rule like:

```css
/* original */
.someclass .someotherclass { xxx: yyy; }


/* modify to */

.someclass .someotherclass,
* /deep/ .someclass /deep/ .someotherclass,
* /deep/ .someclass .someotherclass, /* might be necessary too */
 { xxx: yyy; }
```

If you create all your components (and use only 3rd-party components that don't use shadowDOM) you can put all CSS into the `index.html` page like in Angular.js.

Comment: thanks for the resonse. I am interested in using AngularDart, partly because of shadowDOM. I have read elsewhere that "Bootstrap doesn't play nicely with shadowDOM" but don't understand what that means (or how it is possible). If I use only the Bootstrap CSS (not JS), how does shadowDOM know that it is Bootstrap and choose not to play with it? :) If I use the Angular-ui Bootstrap library with AngularDart and Bootstrap, will the three of them be friends?

Comment: ShadowDOM creates boundaries and you need special selectors for each CSS rule to reach elements inside the shadowDOM (like `/deep/`). A workaround is to add the style link to each component but that doesn't work in all cases. Do you know Angular.dart.ui?

Comment: Yes, when I said Angular-ui BootStrap I meant Angular-dart-ui. I assumed that it was just providing a Dart replacement for Bootstrap js. Am I right in understanding that if I use Angular-dart-ui I will be able to use Bootstrap classes in an AngularDart project with shadowDOM?

Comment: No, the project moved away from shadowDOM when this option was available, because using shadowDOM required cutomizing Bootstrap CSS but it is a main goal of the project to work with vanilla Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a viable alternative to Bootstrap that is shadowDOM compatible?

Comment: I haven't heared of any. ShadowDOM is much about CSS encapsulation. If you use Bootstrap you can't benefit from this encapsulation, why don't you just drop shadowDOM?